# Prove the limit converges $\epsilon$ proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I believe there is an error in the solutions, and wanted to double check here.

I need to show the following sequence converges to the proposed limit.

$\lim \frac{1}{6n^2+1} = 0$

so we need to show that

$\forall \epsilon >0$ It holds that

$\lvert \frac{1}{6n^2+1} \rvert < \epsilon$

Thus we need to prove

$\frac{1}{\epsilon} < 6n^2+1$

$\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon} < 6n^2$

$n > \sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}}$

So we pick some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > \sqrt{\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}}$

It then follow for $n \geq N$ implies $\frac{1}{6n^2+1} < \epsilon$

However the soln's disagree.
they say we need pick an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > \sqrt{\frac{1}{6 \epsilon}}$ which implies...

Isn't this incorrect?

Comment: your proof correct, for showing that it converges to 0 , you just ned to show that there's always an $N$ such for all $n > N$ so and so happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

> $$ \bigg| \frac{1}{6n^2+1}  \bigg| < \frac{1}{6n^2} < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon $$

Comment: what if instead of $\frac{1}{6n^2+1}$ we had  $|\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2+1} |$ 

Can we just use the fact that $\max \{ \cos(n) \} = 1$
so we have $|\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2+1} |<|\frac{1}{n^2+1} | < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$ ?

Comment: @elbarto: Yes that's right. You can see that it is easy to  find that $n> \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ .

Comment: cheers science!

Answer (score 2):

We may write

$$\begin{align}
\left| \frac{1}{6n^2+1} \right| &< \left| \frac{1}{6n^2} \right| \\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{6\epsilon}}$

Comment: @SujaanKunalan It says that you edited this post, yet I see no edit whatsoever.  Please explain.

Comment: Hi, I hope you don't mind, but I just added a `$` to the end of the last line.

Comment: Thanks!  I must have gone back to edit, didn't see any error (you apparently removed the erratum), and re-posted.

Comment: hmm, I thought this may have been the case! Thanks